# How to setup a default schema in SSMS Import Wizard

Tags: sql, database, import, schema, ssms

When using the import wizard, I always want my destination tables to use the schema name of ***[import].{tblName}***.

I've researched but haven't been able to find a way to set this up as a default in the options, vs manually changing it in the mapping phase shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to the `Security` directory in your SSMS

2.Then go to `Logins`

3.Find your Login account, right click - Properties

4. Change the default schema in `User Mapping` page

Comment: I followed these instructions exactly (I even restarted SSMS) but it didn't work.

Comment: is your login account with `sysadmin` role?

Comment: Yes, I have the server role of `sysadmin`.

Comment: Then you cannot change the default schema, that would be fixed to `dbo`, I think you have to manually change schema name every time you import data

Answer (score 0):

Default Schema for the group or account in the User Mapping is required. It cannot be blank and should be set to dbo or whatever schema is allowed for the group to allow SQL Server Import Wizard to work or you get the error DefaultSchema not allowed.